# LINQ join using dates not working

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to create a single list of items based on two separate lists but where a date property from ListA is the same value as a different date property in ListB. I get the correct objects from ListB in my FinalList but not the object in ListA.

Consider the following data

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property InstallDate  As Nullable(Of Date)
       'getters/ setters 
    End Property
    Public Property RemovalDate  As Nullable(Of Date)
       'getters/ setters 
    End Property
End Class

Dim Foo1 As New Foo()
Foo1.InstallDate = 01/12/2014
Foo1.RemovalDate = Nothing

Dim Foo2 As New Foo() 
Foo2.InstallDate = 02/12/2014
Foo2.RemovalDate = Nothing

Dim Foo3 As New Foo()
Foo3.InstallDate = 01/01/2001
Foo3.RemovalDate = 01/12/2014

Dim OriginalList As IList(Of Foo) = {
   Foo1,
   Foo2,
   Foo3
}
```

And my code

```
    Dim ListA As IList(Of Foo) =
        (From X In OriginalList
        Where X.InstallDate IsNot Nothing And X.RemovalDate Is Nothing
        Select X).ToList()

    Dim ListB As IList(Of Foo) =
        (From X In OriginalList
        Where X.RemovalDate IsNot Nothing
        Select X).ToList()

    Dim FinalList As IList(Of Foo) =
        (From LA In ListA
        Group Join LB In ListB On ListA.InstallDate Equals ListB.RemovalDate Into Group _
        From grp In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Select grp).ToList()
```

So I'm expecting `FinalList` to contain objects `Foo1` and `Foo3` but I only get `Foo3`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What classes are you using? What's InstallDate? What's RemovalDate? Why are you using `IList(Of Object)`? How about some sample input/output? Otherwise, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: is  `RemovalDate` a Type which can be Nothing?

Comment: @Plutonix Note that VB.Net uses `Nothing` also to get the default value of a type (like C#'s `default()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected your code:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property InstallDate  As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property RemovalDate  As Nullable(Of Date)
End Class

Dim Foo1 As New Foo()
Foo1.InstallDate = #01/12/2014#
Foo1.RemovalDate = Nothing

Dim Foo2 As New Foo() 
Foo2.InstallDate = #02/12/2014#
Foo2.RemovalDate = Nothing

Dim Foo3 As New Foo()
Foo3.InstallDate = #01/01/2001#
Foo3.RemovalDate = #1/12/2014#

Dim OriginalList As IList(Of Foo) = {
    Foo1,
    Foo2,
    Foo3
}

Dim ListA = (From X In OriginalList
             Where X.InstallDate IsNot Nothing AndAlso X.RemovalDate Is Nothing
             Select X).ToList()

Dim ListB = (From X In OriginalList
             Where X.RemovalDate IsNot Nothing
             Select X).ToList()
```

So, to get `Foo1` and `Foo3`, do a simple `Join`:

```
Dim FinalList = (From LA In ListA
                 Join LB In ListB On LA.InstallDate Equals LB.RemovalDate).ToList()
```

`FinalList` now contains a single item (because there's a single match) with two properties:

`LA` (Foo1) and `LB` (Foo2)

[image]

---

In response to your comment:

To flaten the list, simply use:

```
Dim FinalList = From LA In ListA
                Join LB In ListB On LA.InstallDate Equals LB.RemovalDate
                From item in {LA, LB}
                Select item
```

[image]

Comment: I need FinalList to be a single list of objects to iterate over afterwards.